# why the code can not compile after define my own structural type

Tags: c, header, structure, typedef

Good morning.
I have a problem - I created definition of the myOwnType and I still have a problem with compile. Please help. C language (not C++).

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "additional.h"
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

config.h:

```
#ifndef SRC_CONFIG_H_
#define SRC_CONFIG_H_

#include "additional.h"

typedef struct MyType
{
    int x;
} MyOwnType_t;

#endif /* SRC_CONFIG_H_ */
```

additional.c:

```
#include "config.h"

void foo(MyOwnType_t x)
{

}
```

additional.h:

```
#ifndef SRC_ADDITIONAL_H_
#define SRC_ADDITIONAL_H_

#include "config.h"

extern void foo(MyOwnType_t x);

#endif /* SRC_ADDITIONAL_H_ */
```

Compiler generate error:
..\Src\additional.h:13:10: error: unknown type name 'MyOwnType_t'

Help me please.

Comment: I bet on "horrible include tree" to be the explanation. Need to check carefully.

Comment: It looks bad: config.h includes additional.h and additional.h includes config.h

Comment: But I have a guards everywhere (in each header files)... Why do you think that it is critical loop?

Comment: The guards are what causes the problem, not the solution. They are needed, but you need to plan your include sequence.

Comment: Your config.h file should not include additional.h.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding your includes in additional.c gets you:

```
#ifndef SRC_CONFIG_H_
#define SRC_CONFIG_H_

#ifndef SRC_ADDITIONAL_H_
#define SRC_ADDITIONAL_H_

/* no effect #include "config.h" */
#ifndef SRC_CONFIG_H_
/* not seen because SRC_CONFIG_H_ is already defined here, from above line 2ish */
#endif /* SRC_CONFIG_H_ */

extern void foo(MyOwnType_t x);

#endif /* SRC_ADDITIONAL_H_ */

typedef struct MyType
{
    int x;
} MyOwnType_t;

#endif /* SRC_CONFIG_H_ */

void foo(MyOwnType_t x)
{

}
```

"no effect" refers to the fact that the second include of config.h meets an already defined reinclusion guard, the content is not seen in this place. The content IS seen from the first include, but later, AFTER the content of additional.h which would need the content from config.h.

Cleaning that up gets you:

```
/* no effect #include "config.h" */

extern void foo(MyOwnType_t x);


typedef struct MyType
{
    int x;
} MyOwnType_t;


void foo(MyOwnType_t x)
{

}
```

In the first line, `extern void foo(MyOwnType_t x);` you use a not yet known type, `MyOwnType_t`.
The compiler does not like that.

Comment: Ok, now I see. But my plan is: I want to have one header file (for example config.h) which have all other headers inlcude inside. After this, I want to include in all .c files always only one : config.h. Up to this time (today) I always used to do it and everything was fine and universal because I did not must to include all into all others .c, and I could also call any function (from any .c) in every .c. But now I see it is a risky. Some comments?

Comment: "have one header file... which have all other headers inlcude inside." Don't. Headers should be included based on need. Include all you need, but only those. If you had done so, the problem in this question would not have occurred.

Comment: Of course. Now I see. Thank you all for your answers.